# how to display returned page from managedbean in jsf primefaces panel using ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

### jsf with primefaces

---

am trying to get the page as a string which returned from managed bean and that particular string is configured in faces-config.xml as in navigation rule ,now in jsf primefaces index.xhtml page,i used ajax call to render output page in particular panel but not getting the page in panel, instead just navigating..so how to solve this?Please help

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton action="#{bean.setPage('page1')}" process="@this" 
        update="panel" value="show page 1"/>

    <p:commandButton action="#{bean.setPage('page2')}" process="@this" 
        update="panel" value="show page 2"/>

    <p:panel id="panel" header="dynamic page include">
        <h:panelGroup rendered="#{!empty bean.page}">
            <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/fragments/#{bean.page}.xhtml"/>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```